# Creating a collection that stores objects of derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, collections, constructor

I'm creating a .NET core  menu-based console app that allows you to add and manage players from different sports.

My Player class:

```
abstract class Player
    {
        enum PlayerType
        {
            HockeyPlayer,
            BacketballPlayer,
            BaseballPlayer
        }
        public abstract void Points();
        private long playerId;
        private string playerName;
        private string teamName;
        private int gamesPlayed;

        public long PlayerId
        {
            get { return playerId; }
            set { playerId = value; }
        }
        public string PlayerName
        {
            get { return playerName; }
            set { playerName = value; }
        }
        public string TeamName
        {
            get { return teamName; }
            set { teamName = value; }
        }
        public int GamesPlayed
        {
            get { return gamesPlayed; }
            set { gamesPlayed = value; }
        }
    }
    class HockeyPlayer : Player
    {
        private int assists;
        private int goals;

        public override void Points()
        {
            int totalPoints = assists + (2 * goals);
        }
        public int Assists
        {
            get { return assists; }
            set { assists = value; }
        }
        public int Goals
        {
            get { return goals; }
            set { goals = value; }
        }

    }
    class BasketballPlayer : Player
    {
        private int fieldGoals;
        private int threePointers;
        public override void Points()
        {
            int totalPoints = (fieldGoals - threePointers) + (2 * threePointers);
        }
        public int FieldGoals
        {
            get { return fieldGoals; }
            set { fieldGoals = value; }
        }
        public int ThreePointer
        {
            get { return threePointers; }
            set { threePointers = value; }
        }
    }
    class BaseballPlayer : Player
    {
        private int runs;
        private int homeRuns;
        public override void Points()
        {
            int totalPoints = (runs - homeRuns) + (2 * homeRuns);
        }
        public int Runs
        {
            get { return runs; }
            set { runs = value; }
        }
    }
```

And a snippet of my main class:

```
class Controller
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Player> players = new List<Player>()
            {
                new HockeyPlayer(1, "Mitch Marner", "Toronto Maple Leafs", 5)
            };
```

In the controller I am trying to populate the list with some sample data, but obviously I don't have a constructor in my derived HockeyPlayer class. How do I create a constructor for HockeyPlayer where the arguments are 'playerId', 'playerName', 'teamName', and 'gamesPlayed' which come from the parent class. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

Comment: `How do I create a constructor for HockeyPlayer where the arguments` Can you show us your _attempt_ to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A funny thing is that you are using 'object initialization' for the list, but trying to call the constructor of HockeyPlayer, where you also could use the object initialization method.

The object initialization is executed after the constructor (assigning properties) but enables construction and property initialization in one single statement

For example:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>()
{
    new HockeyPlayer(1, "Mitch Marner", "Toronto Maple Leafs", 5);
};
```

---

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>()
{
    new HockeyPlayer
    {
        PlayerId = 1, 
        PlayerName = "Mitch Marner", 
        TeamName = "Toronto Maple Leafs", 
        GamesPlayed = 5
    }
};
```

---

Constructors are usefull when certain parameters are mandatory. This way you force an initial value for a field/property.

Object initializers is just syntactic sugar for constructing and assigning properties. With a big difference (like i said) an object initializer can be treated as a single statement. (therefor you can pass it as an argument to a function.)

```
var player = new HockeyPlayer
{
    PlayerId = 1, 
    PlayerName = "Mitch Marner", 
    TeamName = "Toronto Maple Leafs", 
    GamesPlayed = 5
}
```

VS

```
var player = new HockeyPlayer();
player.PlayerId = 1; 
player.PlayerName = "Mitch Marner"; 
player.TeamName = "Toronto Maple Leafs";
player.GamesPlayed = 5;
```